# Extra value 'None' being printed out and I don't know why

Tags: xml, python-3.x, elementtree

I am trying to parse an XML document using two functions one to parse the header and another to parse the data. And I keep getting a 'None' value at the end of each function printout. I do not know why this is happening.

Any help or suggestions will be much appreciated. Thank you.

XML file:

```
<datafile>
    <header>
        <name>header_name</name>
    </header>
    <game name="game_name">
    </game>
</datafile>
```

Code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def parse_header(file):
    tree = ET.parse(file)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for header in root.iter('header'):
        for name in header.iter('name'):
            if name.text is not None:
                print(name.text)

def parse_games(file):
    tree = ET.parse(file)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for game in root.iter('game'):
        for key, value in game.items():
            if value is not None:
                print(value)

print(parse_header('test.dat'))
print(parse_games('test.dat'))
```

Output:

```
header_name
None
game_name
None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions that do not have an explicit returning value return `None` in Python, so both of your `print` calls in the main program end up printing `None`s since the functions they are printing return `None`s implicitly.

Change:

```
print(parse_header('test.dat'))
print(parse_games('test.dat'))
```

to:

```
parse_header('test.dat')
parse_games('test.dat')
```